# Spring Integration - Unable to process multipart/form-data with Http-inbound Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

It is a Spring Integration (based on Spring Boot) project, I've configured Spring Integration application as below,

Configuration xml:

```
<int:channel id="httpChannel"/>

 <int-http:inbound-gateway  supported-methods="GET,POST" request-channel="httpChannel" reply-channel="outputChannel" path="/"
  message-converters="converter" 
 /> 
 <bean id="converter" class="in.tc.springintegrationdemo.CustomConverter" />
    
    
  <int:transformer ref="customTransformer" input-channel="httpChannel" output-channel="outputChannel" />  

  <bean id="customTransformer" class="in.tc.springintegrationdemo.MultipartTransformer" />  
  
   <bean class="in.tc.springintegrationdemo.MessageUpdateBean" id="printMessage"/> 
<int:service-activator ref="printMessage" method="print"  input-channel="outputChannel">
</int:service-activator>
```

CustomConverter defined as below

```
public class CustomConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<MultiValueMap<String,?>> {

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
      ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return Collections.singletonList(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    }

    @Override
    public MultiValueMap<String,?> read(Class<? extends MultiValueMap<String,?>> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
         MultiValueMap<String, ?> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
         String str = "";
        MediaType contentType = inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputMessage.getBody(), contentType.getCharset()));
                while((str=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                
                    //code to retrieve multipart data
                }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(MultiValueMap<String,?> t, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

for multipart/form-data, I'm always getting a blank payload in CustomConverter class.

I've also tried adding a multipartResolver as below

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/> but it has the same result.
```

I've followed a similar question on stackoverflow **[Spring Integration dsl - HTTP inbound gateway consume multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879286/spring-integration-dsl-http-inbound-gateway-consume-multipart-form-data)**.
But for me it's not working.

Multipart/form-data payload

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: d24d89ef-c52b-492a-96b9-6ef6807e8d1a
Host: localhost:9090
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------865732735860935509694157
Content-Length: 217

----------------------------865732735860935509694157
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""; filename="testfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

testcontent
----------------------------865732735860935509694157--
```

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to ditch your `CustomConverter` in favor of existing one out-of-the-box - `MultipartAwareFormHttpMessageConverter`, which is really presented by default in any `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` bean definition.

Since you say that you use Spring Boot then you don't need to do anything with the `multipartResolver` - it is auto-configured for us out-of-the-box in the `MultipartAutoConfiguration`.

If that still doesn't work for you, I'd be glad to look into a simple and short version of your project to play with, reproduce and possible fix.

Not related: any chances to understand why do use XML configuration, but not Java & Annotations or even Java DSL?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I removed the CustomConverter and added a Transformer to process the multipart-formdata but it receives an empty map as part of payload. As you have suggested to try with Annotation and DSL , I created a sample project based on DSL to process multipart/form-data. But it also fails to process it. I'm getting an empty Map here too.  The DSL based project present at https://github.com/bharatguru1983/demo  [link](https://github.com/bharatguru1983/demo).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good. I will look into that tomorrow

Comment: How can I test this? This is your project, so only you know what and how to call. Would you mind to share some description how to test this? Or even better add a unit test to confirm the problem.